# Are there versions of the Intersecting chords/secants theorem that work on non-cyclic quadrilaterals?

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

[The Intersecting chords theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersecting_chords_theorem)

[The Intersecting secants theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersecting_secants_theorem)

You know how the [Cosine rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) is a generalisation of Pythagoras' theorem in that it works for all triangles- not just right-angled ones.

I was wondering if there is a generalisation of either (or both together) of the above theorems that works for all quadrilaterals $ABCD,$ not just cyclic ones.

Comment: FWIW those are not primarily related to quadrilaterals. Both of them follow straight from the [power of a point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) properties, and that's fundamentally tied to a circle.